# What is the best way to identify what caused a CPU spike?

Tags: windows, cpu, freeze, process, task-manager

In Windows Task Manager History I can see that there was a CPU spike and my computer freezes.

And I can see when I sort the view on highest CPU percentage which processes take most of the CPU.

But whenever the PC hangs / freezes, it doesn't update the view so I am unable to capture it.

All I can see in my CPU graph is that there was a spike a while ago.

[image]

What is the best way to identify what caused a CPU spike?

Comment: Historically? None, unless it was logged as a critical system event in the event viewer. If you want to monitor it going forward, you'll need to use Perfmon with a trace running, logging quite a lot of thread information.

Comment: Depends on how deep you want to go.  The proper tool for really digging in, if that's necessary, is ETW - Event Tracing For Windows - and Bruce Dawson has an [excellent series of blog posts about it](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/etw-central/).

Comment: It's fairly uncommon for a computer to become completely unresponsive even during 100% multi-core CPU usage. You should right-click the graph and enable "Show kernel times". Odds are there is some blocking process which has taken full system priority; usually this points to an antivirus software. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204416/do-anti-virus-programs-scan-running-processes

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One tool that could help is
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Leave Process Explorer running minimized while the computer
is working. Immediately after a CPU spike, bring it up and
start menu *View > System Information...* or just hit
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

In the System Information screen, hover the mouse over the spike
and you will see the process causing it.

[image]